# what is the meaning of security_token in system, native_context in global in node heap snapshot

Tags: node.js, heap-memory

I'm searching on the node heap snapshot.
And I found security_token in system and native_context in global in
the snapshot.

They have a small shallow size and a very large retained size.

So I want to know the details of these.

Anyone who knows this?

[image: capture - chrome heap snapshots]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please clarify your question. What do you mean by details of these? Could you be more specific?

Comment: @Ayrad I added a capture of heap snapshot, I want to know what are the security_token and native_context. and why these have a lot of retained size.

Comment: my question regarding native_context in global is how do i track down what is in native_context?

Answer (score 2):

Small intro, Node.js is written in C++ and JS engine V8 is written in the C++ too, so when people say `native something` in Node.js they usually mean C++ stuff that can be called from the JS code or not and etc.

In that particular case `native_context` is just the object that stores some fields from the Native side of the Node.js. Even datatypes are C++ entities under the hood and you are operating with these "native" entities.

There is no way you can change or modify the `native_context` because this thing is defined during the build of the Node.js executable and defined in the C++ code. You can dig up more about these in the Node.js repository in C++ source code if you want to know more about that.

https://github.com/nodejs/node

UPD: You can search it in the code e.g. here is what you can find, but you need to know some C++ to understand.

[image]